# R: Stacked Vertical Bar graph with two separate categories in GGPlot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to produce a stacked vertical bar graph, but I'm not sure how to reshape my dataset to satisfy the expectations of ggplot.

I have a dataframe with two columns, "killed" and "injured", each associated with a State name.  I want a vertical bar graph with the #injured per state stacked on top of the #killed.

I can produce the standard bar graph like this:

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=state,y=killed)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity") + 
  coord_flip() +
  ggtitle("Mass Shooting Killings and Injuries") + 
  labs(x="Killings and Injuries", y="State") +
  ggtitle("Victims")
```

I know the way to "stack" the bar graph is to add a fill component to the ggplot aesthetics, but the problem is that I'm not sure how to do so in a way that fits my data.

Fake reproducible example:

```
data <- read.table(text = "state killed injured 
1 Arkansas 23 50 
2 Alabama 10 20
3 Texas 19 18
4 Ohio 14 15
5 Illinois 3 5", sep = "", header=T)

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=state,y=killed)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity") + 
  coord_flip() +
  ggtitle("Mass Shooting Killings and Injuries") + 
  labs(x="Killings and Injuries", y="State") +
  ggtitle("Victims")
```

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your dataframe?

Comment: Just added one.  The data are proprietary, so I just made something up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to reshape the data.frame using `melt` to get this plot:

```
temp <- melt(data, id="state")
ggplot(data=temp, aes(x=state,y=value, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack",stat="identity") + 
  coord_flip() +
  ggtitle("Mass Shooting Killings and Injuries") + 
  labs(x="Killings and Injuries", y="State") +
  ggtitle("Victims")
```

[image]

Comment: Melt is key -- noted